# Отключение функции Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, прокрутка

Здравствуйте.

Есть функция на скролл

```
$(function scrollFunction() {  
          $(window).scroll(function() {
              if($(this).scrollTop() != 0) {
                $('#topNubex').fadeIn();
              } else {
                $('#topNubex').fadeOut();
              }
          });
          $('#topNubex').click(function() {
            $('body,html').animate({scrollTop:0},1000);
          });


      });
```

Вопрос - можно ли ее убрать при проверке определенных условий? т.е. если ширина экрана больше 1000, кнопка скролла должна быть на экране. Если меньше - не должно быть

Comment: `if ($(window).width() >= 1000) { ... }`

Answer (score 2):

Да можно։

```
$(function scrollFunction() { 

var width = $(window).width();
if(width < 1000){
 $('#topNubex').fadeOut();
return false;
}

          $(window).scroll(function() {
              if($(this).scrollTop() != 0) {
                $('#topNubex').fadeIn();
              } else {
                $('#topNubex').fadeOut();
              }
          });
          $('#topNubex').click(function() {
            $('body,html').animate({scrollTop:0},1000);
          });


      });
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(function() {
  var $window = $(window);
  var $nudex  = $('#topNubex');

  $window.on('load resize' onResize);
  $nudex.on('click', onClick);

  function onResize() {
    /*
    * Что бы событие вообще не триггерилось когда не нужно ...
    */
    $window.off('scroll', onScroll);
    if($window.width() >= 1000) $window.on('scroll', onScroll);
  }

  function onScroll() {
    if($(this).scrollTop() > 0) $nudex.fadeIn();
    else $nudex.fadeOut();
  }

  function onClick() {
    $('body, html').animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 1000);
  }
});
```